# Symbol LS3578 Bluetooth SPP profile

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, barcode-scanner

After setting up a Serial Port Profile for a Bluetooth device, should I be able to use the .NET Serial Port class to read from and write to that device, or is it more complex than that?  Would someone kindly explain how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct.  Once your device is paired and the profile is working and the drivers are loaded, you can access it just like any other serial port on your computer.

You can't however, get Bluetooth management info that way, such as signal strength and pairing status.  For that, you need to use the API for whatever Bluetooth stack is in use.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Brad. Before purchasing the scanner is there any way to verify its compatibility with my Motorola ES400 phone? The scanner claims to support SPP in its manual, and the phone has Windows Mobile 6.5, I just don't know if they'll work together with the SPP.  (Are there any drivers I need?)

Comment: @Pytice, no idea.  When it comes to Bluetooth, even if you have a couple devices that *should* work together, whether they do or not is another issue.  I don't know why, but getting Bluetooth stuff talking is a hassle.  It's great when it works though.  Your best bet would be to buy from a place that accepts returns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however... the LS3578-ER that I purchased in 2013 worked fine with Bluetooth SPP and a .NET `SerialPort`.  However, two recently purchased scanners, manufactured in 2015, fail to connect properly when the serial port opens.  Tech support was basically useless and told me that method of connecting was no longer supported, even though the part # was the same.  The firmware had apparently changed.  It didn't seem possible to revert the firmware either.

On the 2nd model I managed to get it working as a USB HID device (VID 05E0 PID 0600) but the latest one doesn't work, and oddly shows up with a different PID (1200).  Again, for the same scanner part #.

So don't bang your head against the wall too hard if you can't get it to work.

We're completely frustrated with Symbol/Motorola over this.